# Why is my simple Ruby SQLite3 example failing?

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, dbi

In my attempt to learn Ruby, I've been reading [Mr. Neighborly's Humble Little Ruby Book](http://humblelittlerubybook.com/).

Most examples have been very easy to follow giving me a good introduction to Ruby, however I can't run DB related examples easily.

I'm trying to run this code: (slightly modified from the example given in the book)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'dbi'

DBI.connect('DBI:SQLite3:testdb', 'ruby', 'ruby') do | dbh |
  dbh.do('CREATE TABLE slugs(name varchar(20), age int);') rescue puts "TABLE slugs already exists."

  sql = "INSERT INTO slugs (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)"

  dbh.prepare(sql) do |st|
    1.upto(20) do |i|
      st.execute("slug #{i}", "#{i}")
    end
  end

end
```

When run, it inserts one row in the database, then it gives me the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:41:in `bind_param': library routine called out of sequence (SQLite3::MisuseException)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:41:in `bind_params'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:37:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:37:in `bind_params'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dbd-sqlite3-1.2.5/lib/dbd/sqlite3/statement.rb:71:in `bind_params'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb:115:in `execute'
    from /media/dev/ruby-prax/moi.rb:12
    from /media/dev/ruby-prax/moi.rb:11:in `upto'
    from /media/dev/ruby-prax/moi.rb:11
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/database.rb:61:in `prepare'
    from /media/dev/ruby-prax/moi.rb:10
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/driver.rb:41:in `connect'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:148:in `connect'
    from /media/dev/ruby-prax/moi.rb:5
TABLE slugs already exists.
```

I am on Ubuntu 10.04 at the moment.
Version info:

```
tlee@tim-ubuntu:/media/dev/ruby-prax$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
tlee@tim-ubuntu:/media/dev/ruby-prax$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.0)
dbd-mysql (0.4.4)
dbd-odbc (0.2.5)
dbd-sqlite3 (1.2.5)
dbi (0.4.5)
deprecated (3.0.0, 2.0.1)
erubis (2.6.6)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
extlib (0.9.15)
json_pure (1.4.6)
mysql (2.8.1)
rack (1.2.1)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
thin (1.2.7)
thor (0.14.1)
tlee@tim-ubuntu:/media/dev/ruby-prax$ sqlite3 --version
3.6.22
tlee@tim-ubuntu:/media/dev/ruby-prax$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem.  There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi/issues#issue/5) about the SQLite driver for DBD failing when you use a prepared INSERT statement more than once.  Personally, I've taken the recommendation in the answer there of moving to [RDBI](http://github.com/rdbi/), since Ruby/DBI is apparently no longer being maintained.  Moving to RDBI required very minimal code changes.

Comment: Is RDBI is still a good idea? It seems that there are no commits there, but I am unsure is it because project was abandoned or because there are nearly no bugs and it is rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition is:

```
slugs(name varchar(20), age int);
```

but you are trying to insert:

```
st.execute("slug #{i}", "#{i}")
```

Note that `"#{i}"` is not an integer, it's a string. Change it to `i`, as in this example:

```
st.execute("slug #{i}", i)
```

Then see what happens.

Comment: Good pick up! But, after changing it, it didn't make any difference. I'm seeing the exactly same behaviour. In fact, for sqlite3 it doesn't seem to make much difference for this simple inserts whether I define the columns as varchar or int. I tried with slugs(name, age) and still got the same error.

Comment: I would expect it to give the same error if you try to pass an numeric for "name" since that is a type mismatch also. Name has to be a string, and age has to be an integer/fixnum.

Comment: Another error you *could* see when bringing up a database while testing is if you have a "distinct" or "unique" clause for a field, that restricts that field to only unique values. Trying to rerun code that tries to insert sequential values will make the DB mad, forcing a delete of all rows before each run. But I don't think you defined any fields with a "distinct" clause.

Comment: SQLite treats column types more like hints rather than strict rules to enforce. The SQLite website has [more information](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) on how types work.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow think that several of sqlite3 libraries on Ruby are missing reset and clear methods for the statement class.

When same SQL statement is executed repeatedly, a statement is prepared once and executed with a fresh set of values. But after the statement is executed and before it is re-bound, it needs to be reset (and often cleared). The point is that it is faster to reset a used statement than "compiling and optimizing" the same SQL over and over again. Most of you probably know all this... but here's the link to the SQLite documentation of the relevant part:

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

I don't see reset and clear methods in SQLite3::Statement class, so these might be somehow missed from this implementation, or there is some other mechanism to reset/clear automatically when reused, but that mechanism is somehow not triggered. However, it is not even mentioned in the documentation... at least I couldn't find it.

I think clear_bindings and reset methods are missing from SQLite3::Statement class.

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/158